# How do I have my drop down selections submit in the HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have these conditional drop lists behaving on screen as expected, but I cannot get the selected values from the drop downs to output in the HTML form (I can if I don't include the javascript). Only the text inputs are outputing as per the xml result below (Company & Add1). I want the xml to contain the Location from the first drop down, and the selected city from the conditional 2nd drop down.

```html
<body>
<form action="http://TESTPLANETPRESS:8080/ObtainQuote" method="GET" >
    <fieldset>
       <legend>Location</legend>
       <select id="country" class="source" onchange="updateSelectTarget()">
          <option value="England">England</option>
          <option value="France">France</option>
          <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
       </select>   
       <select id="England">
          <option value="Birmingham">Birmingham</option>
          <option value="Liverpool">Liverpool</option>
          <option value="London">London</option>
       </select>
       <select id="France" class="hidden">
          <option value="Lyon">Lyon</option>
          <option value="Marseille">Marseille</option>
          <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
       </select>
       <select id="Germany" class="hidden">
          <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
          <option value="Hamburg">Hamburg</option>
          <option value="Munich">Munich</option>
       </select>
       <label for="Company">Company:</label><input type="text" name="Company" value="Google">
   <label for="Add1">Add1:</label><input type="text" name="Add1" value="1 Nowhere Street">
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
 function updateSelectTarget () {
    var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    var targets = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var len = targets.length;
    for (var i = len - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    if (targets[i].id == id) {
    targets[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
    targets[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    }
 }
 
 function initChangeHandler () {
    var el = document.getElementById("country");
    el.onchange = updateSelectTarget;
    el.onchange();
 }
 window.onload = initChangeHandler;
</script>
</body>
```

Current XML result, (Does not include the results from the two drop downs).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<request type="GET">

<paths count="0"/>


-<values count="2">

<Company>Google</Company>

<Add1>1 Nowhere Street</Add1>

</values>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the value attribute or the text? Based on [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) (similar to the first part), `.value` should work for the value attribute and `.text` for the text that is selected.

Also, please make two different questions instead of one question with 2 questions nested inside.

Comment: I'm after the text to appear in my xml with the Company and Add1, afer submitting the form..

Comment: I actually don't know XML, sorry, you have to find another person.